# Django REST Framework UniqueTogetherValidator

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

### Problem Description:

The DRF UniqueTogetherValidator is displaying some odd behaviour.
For example:

*models.py*

```
class MyModel1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    field2 = models.ForeignKey('MyModel2', on_delete...)
    
class MyModel2(models.Model):
    field3 = models.IntegerField()
```

*serializer.py*

```
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueTogetherValidator

class MyModel1Seriealizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel1
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=MyModel1.objects.all(),
                fields=('field1', 'field2_id')
            )
        ]
```

When the condition is violated by `field1` only, it reports back a good 400 response with a message in `non_field_errors`, but when the violated field is `field2` (or its `_id`), the server gives back a response code 500 (meaning Django caught it at the database/ORM level).

The actual use-case is [here on my GitHub](https://github.com/sharifanani/part_management_backend/issues/1#issue-453344900).

### Full traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /parts/10/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: part_management_part.class_code_id, part_management_part.number

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 116, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 84, in partial_update
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 70, in update
    self.perform_update(serializer)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 80, in perform_update
    serializer.save()
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 209, in save
    self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/part_management/serializers.py", line 55, in update
    instance.save()
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 851, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 900, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 760, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1429, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/anani/PycharmProjects/part_management_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: part_management_part.class_code_id, part_management_part.number
[06/Jun/2019 23:37:04] "PATCH /parts/10/ HTTP/1.1" 500 22340
```

Comment: Show full error traceback.

Comment: Why don't you show the error traceback?

Comment: Have you tried `field2` instead of `field2_id`?

Comment: @robotHamster show complete error traceback so that we can help

Comment: @mrzrm didn't want the question to get really long, I put on github, and it's also here now

Comment: @mrzrm using `field2` always results in the `500` error

Comment: did you ever receive an answer to this issue?

Comment: @kunambi I think I just ended up restructuring to avoid the problem, but it's been a while now

Answer (score 0):

if field2_id is foreign key, you don't need to put field like that.
just put field2

```
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueTogetherValidator

class MyModel1Seriealizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel1
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=MyModel1.objects.all(),
                fields=('field1', 'field2')
            )
        ]
```

and you can try post json data like this:

```
{
  "field2": 1,
  "field1": "test",
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! doing that results in the `500 error` always. i.e., it skips DRF and gets caught by Django. I should maybe note that I have the serializer of `MyModel2` also in my the serializer for `MyModel1`, I edited the question to reflect